# How do use perl to trigger another perl scipt running on another machine?

Tags: perl, ssh, execution

Need a way to have a perl script running on one machine run a perl script running on another.

The remote machine config is:

- CentOS-5.5,
- it's on the same network is the requesting machine,
- has a DNS,
- ports-open(SSH,HTTP)

Questions, feedback, comments -- just comment, thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
system("ssh user@remotemachine perl <remote script's full path>");
```

will run the script on remote machine.

you may want to ssh without password, check: http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: +1, thanks for posting an answer. So, Perl's System() does not allow you to store the password in the script, right? And your suggested work around is to create and store authentication keys outside of the perl script in this case using OpenSSH, right?

Comment: ssh doesn't have an option to specify password as a parameter, it doesn't have anything to do with system()

Comment: @All: The docs on system() are here http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Answer (score 3):

As @Nylon Smile mentioned, you can use `system` to invoke the system's ssh client. If you want to do this without relying on external binaries (in particular because you want to handle password authentication differently), try `Net::SSH::Perl`, available from CPAN.

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new('host');
$ssh->login('username', 'password');
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit_code) = $ssh->cmd(
    'perl some_script.pl --with=some_args',
    'optionally, some stdin for that script'
);
```

Net::SSH::Perl can be a bit of a pain to install, but there are several other CPAN modules (most of which rely on an installed OpenSSH) and are a bit easier to deal with while providing a similar api.  See also `Net::SSH` and `Net::OpenSSH`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'd seen those, but it was not clear to me why; eg ssh does not have a password parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are fine for a one-off, but if you're doing this sort of thing a lot, you may want to look into some sort of messaging system like AMPQ (e.g. RabbitMQ) and set up queue listeners.

Comment: +1 Thanks, interesting -- what are reasons you know when it makes sense to use a message queuing protocol?

Comment: Well, reason #1 would be if you do it a lot in general. Other reasons include if you have more than one "kind" of thing being done (for instance, running a program or script, changing a config, adding data to a database, logging, etc) it can be very useful to have a simple way to go about all these things in one apparent location. The basic idea is to set up listeners on the machines/vms involved that poll the queue for instructions to them, and then any process that needs to ask another machine to do something just drops a JSON, XML, or whatever message into the queue.